# Monitoring Power on Twin 110v lines

Tags: power

I am wanting to monitor my household's power from the single phase 3 line input I have coming into the house.

I have 2 CT clamps to put over each of the "hot" legs to measure the current, and then I was going to measure the voltage using an AC-AC adapter (to step down the voltage and isolate from the mains) in order to correctly determine the power.

My question is - shouldn't I actually be using two AC-AC adapters, one for each side of the fuse box?  Although I guess if they are out by 180 degrees in relation to one another, then I can just determine the voltage through one AC-AC adapter and use the 180 degree fact to calculate what is on the other hot leg?  Is there a problem with this approach?

Comment: I would be careful doing this. These voltages and current can be deadly.

Comment: Use a DMM to measure the voltage on each hot phase to neutral a couple of times over the course of a day.  If they're similar to within your acceptable error tolerance, you can just measure one (or measure line-to-line voltage and divide by 2 when computing power per phase).  If they differ a lot phase to phase, then you'll probably need to measure them independently.

Comment: "from the single phase 3 line input" - sounds more like you mean "from the TWO phase 3 line input"

Comment: @Grant: In the USA, residential power is delivered using a single-phase transformer that has a center-tapped secondary with the center tap grounded, giving 120V - 0V - 120V, or 240V from "hot" to "hot". Hence, "single phase, three line".

Comment: @DaveTweed ah, I learn something new every day :)

Comment: @DeanB - Thanks for the pointer, I'll check that.  If it is the case, I'll go with one and assume the 180 degree is ok.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To measure single-phase power, simply **measuring voltage and current does not yield actual power** with any precision. Any power factor issues will skew the results, often badly.

Consider instead a solution like [this one from SiLabs](http://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/AN638.pdf) with their Si8902, which uses digital-side isolation, not line-side. Or here is [another approach from Linear Tech](http://circuits.linear.com/292) using their LM2940, where isolation is at line side. Similar isolated solutions exist from Texas Instruments, and many other companies.

If you must measure in discrete parts,

- Measuring current on both live and neutral legs is often useful - a difference would indicate an earth leak inside the domestic network. Inductive clamps are safe enough.
- Measure voltage across live to neutral using either an isolated voltmeter or an isolating voltage sense IC
- Measure phase on both voltage and current sense channels, so you can have a PFC correct power figure such as the utility company bills you for.

An important point to keep in mind:
Most utility companies frown upon any equipment connected on the distribution side of your domestic entry point / fuse box - **all devices including power monitoring must be on your side of the fence**. Also, connecting anything at all beyond the fuse box may violate UL or equivalent certification for your geography, leaving your home exposed to diminished insurance coverage.

Comment: "Measuring current on both live and neutral legs is often useful - a difference would indicate an earth leak inside the domestic network." - True for single phase, but the split phase topology that the OP is referring to will have normal nonzero neutral current as a function of asymmetric loading between the two (sub) phases.  Only phase-phase loads will be balanced with respect to neutral current; phase-neutral loads will contribute to neutral current (one way or the other), and are normal and expected.

Comment: @DeanB Fair point.